Trying to track .bundle/.app using git-lfs, but lfs treats it as a git trackable and looks inside the folder
I am trying to familiarize myself with git LFS, tried LFS with .png, .jpg and .zip , after adding them to tracking list they would show up as LFS objects (
git lfs status

git lfs ls-files

)
and its pretty straight forward from there. But as a part of a project I am trying to track files with mac's .bundle / .app extensions using git LFS. After adding the extension to tracked list, it still treats the file as git trackable and views the bundle as a folder as opposed to a file.
I am trying to find a work around to track the .bundle/ .app extensions using LFS.
